# Jersey client in android with protocol buffer

Tags: android

I would like to create a Jersey client in Android using protocol buffer.
I am using the following libraries:
jersey-client-1.8.jar
jersey-core-1.8.jar
protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar

The code I have written:

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientRequest;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.Builder;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.ClientFilter;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter;

BaseRestClient client = BaseRestClient.create("", "");

 HTTPBasicAuthFilter authenticationFilter =
     new    HTTPBasicAuthFilter(username, password);

client.addFilter(authenticationFilter);
..........
..........
WebResource webResourceGetMea = client.resource(url);
webResourceGetMea = webResourceGetMea.path("/accounts").path("/login");
ClientResponse responseGetMea = webResourceGetMea.type("application/x-protobuf").get(ClientResponse.class);
```

The above code is running successfully as Java main() application but when I am running it on Android the responseGetMea() object is null (last line of code).

I am using the "application/x-protobuf" because in such way it was defined on server side.
I have added the INTERNET permission in my Android application.
I also checked the URL from Android browser and when I click it, it prompts me to input the user name and the password(the expected behaviour).

I really appreciate any help.

Regards,
kalgik

Answer (score 1):

An addition... When trying to POST with the version of Buscador at the previous link it complained with some errors. The new version of Buscador that works for POSTing is the following,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

import com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder.DefaultServiceIteratorProvider;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder.ServiceIteratorProvider;

public class Buscador<T> extends ServiceIteratorProvider<T>
{
private static final HashMap<String, String[]> SERVICES = new HashMap<String, String[]>();

private static final String[] com_sun_jersey_spi_HeaderDelegateProvider = new String[] {
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.LocaleProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.EntityTagProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.MediaTypeProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.CacheControlProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.NewCookieProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.CookieProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.URIProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.DateProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.StringProvider"

};
private static final String[] com_sun_jersey_spi_inject_InjectableProvider = new String[] {
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.xml.SAXParserContextProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.xml.XMLStreamReaderContextProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.xml.DocumentBuilderFactoryProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.xml.TransformerFactoryProvider"
};
private static final String[] javax_ws_rs_ext_MessageBodyReader = new String[] {
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.RenderedImageProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.MimeMultipartProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormMultivaluedMapProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$App",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$Text",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$App",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$Text",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$App",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$Text",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$App",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$Text",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader"
};
private static final String[] javax_ws_rs_ext_MessageBodyWriter = new String[] {
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.RenderedImageProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.MimeMultipartProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormMultivaluedMapProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$App",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$Text",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$App",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$Text",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$App",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$Text",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider",
        "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter"
};

static
{
    SERVICES.put("com.sun.jersey.spi.HeaderDelegateProvider",
        com_sun_jersey_spi_HeaderDelegateProvider);
    SERVICES.put("com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.InjectableProvider",
        com_sun_jersey_spi_inject_InjectableProvider);
    SERVICES.put("javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader", javax_ws_rs_ext_MessageBodyReader);
    SERVICES.put("javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter", javax_ws_rs_ext_MessageBodyWriter);
}

DefaultServiceIteratorProvider defaultServiceIteratorProvider = new ServiceFinder.DefaultServiceIteratorProvider();

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public Iterator<Class<T>> createClassIterator(Class<T> service, String serviceName,
    ClassLoader loader, boolean ignoreOnClassNotFound)
{
    String[] classesNames = SERVICES.get(serviceName);

    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!! serviceName: " + serviceName + " !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

    if(classesNames==null)
    {
        return defaultServiceIteratorProvider.createClassIterator(service, serviceName, loader, ignoreOnClassNotFound);
    }

    int length = classesNames.length;
    ArrayList<Class<T>> classes = new ArrayList<Class<T>>(length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            classes.add((Class<T>) Class.forName(classesNames[i]));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //return null;
    return classes.iterator();
}

@Override
public Iterator<T> createIterator(Class<T> service, String serviceName, ClassLoader loader,
    boolean ignoreOnClassNotFound)
{
    String[] classesNames = SERVICES.get(serviceName);
    int length = classesNames.length;
    ArrayList<T> classes = new ArrayList<T>(length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            classes.add(service.cast(Class.forName(classesNames[i]).newInstance()));
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return classes.iterator();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I employed the solution offered at,

[java.lang.NullPointerException on Android](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/java-lang-NullPointerException-on-Android-td4212447.html)

as proposed by

> Lucas Ventura, Aug 25, 2010; 9:15am

and it worked like a charm.

[EDIT]
Well, small comment/correction. Running in an HTC phone, caused the app to destroy/create when i minimised (not sure if this is normal) and re-opened. The solution proposed mandates that the Jersey client object and the ServiceFinder setting should occur in a static context. This should give a clue,

```
private static final BaseRestClient client; 
static { 
    client = BaseRestClient.create("", ""); // just a helper class
    ServiceFinder.setIteratorProvider(new Buscador());
}
```

Otherwise, the class loading fix complains in a rather strange way. Hope this helps someone...

Cheers!