# Jersey Client thrown NullPointerException on Android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, jersey

I'm trying to consume an atom feed using the jersey-client library but not having much luck. This is the code I'm using:

```
    Client client = Client.create();
    ClientResponse response = client.resource("http://192.168.1.65:9998/tweets").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_ATOM_XML).get(ClientResponse.class);
    String responseString = response.getEntity(String.class);
```

Which originally led to me getting this exception:

> E/AndroidRuntime(13126): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13126):  at javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.java:119)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13126):  at > com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getType(ClientResponse.java:614)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13126):  at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:531)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13126):  at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:506)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13126):  at com.pivotallabs.tracker.TweetsService.onHandleIntent(TweetsService.java:55)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13126):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:59)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13126):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13126):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13126):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

I tried to use the solution from this question - [Jersey client in android with protocol buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540711/jersey-client-in-android-with-protocol-buffer) - which involved writing a custom ServiceIteratorProvider and that got rid of the first problem but then created a new problem where the ServiceIteratorProvider was looking for an implementation of com.sun.jersey.client.proxy.ViewProxyProvider.

I created a fake implementation of that:

```
public class FakeViewProvider implements com.sun.jersey.client.proxy.ViewProxyProvider {

    public <T> ViewProxy<T> proxy(Client client, Class<T> tClass) {
        Class[] interfaces = new Class[] {tClass};
        return (ViewProxy<T>) Proxy.newProxyInstance(tClass.getClassLoader(), interfaces, new Delegator(interfaces, new Object[]{}));
    }
}
```

And plugged it in just before the call to Client.create:

ServiceFinder.setIteratorProvider(new Buscador());

...but now I get this error instead:

> E/AndroidRuntime(12789): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12789):    at com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder.toClassArray(ServiceFinder.java:595)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12789):    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServiceClasses(ProviderServices.java:318)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12789):    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServiceClasses(ProviderServices.java:311)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12789):    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServices(ProviderServices.java:159)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12789):    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.init(Client.java:249)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12789):    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.access$000(Client.java:118)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12789):    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:191)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12789):    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:187)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12789):    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12789):    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.(Client.java:187)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12789):    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.(Client.java:159)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12789):    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:669)

I'm pretty much stuck so if anyone has any ideas/has solved this problem then that'd be cool!

Cheers, Mark

Comment: For me is more that you put the FakeViewProvider class into wrong directory. SPI is trying to get it but to no avail. Look at [http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/04/07/creating-service-provider-interface](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/04/07/creating-service-provider-interface) for how to configure SPI correctly.

Comment: META-INF/services/jersey-client-components

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342506/jersey-client-on-android-nullpointerexception?answertab=active#tab-top) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you should wrap your code in 
`if(response.getStatus() == Response.Status.OK && response.hasEntity()){...}`
Are you sure the request is returning non-empty response?

Comment: I tried adding that conditional statement to the code but it still throws the same exception. The interesting thing is that the same code when just run on my machine rather than Android works fine...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue when testing on an Asus Memopad and a galaxyS4 test device. Here's how I fixed it.

```
 Client client = Client.create();
ClientResponse response = client.resource("http://192.168.1.65:9998/tweets").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_ATOM_XML).get(ClientResponse.class);

//change to this. pull the input stream from the response and use apache commons to form the input stream into a string
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    try {
        IOUtils.copy(response.getEntityInputStream(), writer, Charset.defaultCharset());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String theString = writer.toString();
    String output = theString;
```

you will need Apache commons http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi for this to work. I hope it helps.