# When using Jersey for restful api in Android app I get this error:

Tags: java, android, rest

1. Here is the code that i am using :

   ```
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.util.logging.Logger;
   import java.io.FileInputStream;
   import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
   import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;


    public class Fragment_2 extends Fragment {
   static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Fragment_2.class.getSimpleName());

   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

       public void run() {

           try {
                String base64 = null;
                   String imageDataString2 = null;
                   File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/2013-03-27 00.22.48.jpg");

                   try {
                          // Reading a Image file from file system
                          FileInputStream imageInFile = new FileInputStream(file);
                          byte imageData[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];
                          imageInFile.read(imageData);

                          // Converting Image byte array into Base64 String
                          String imageDataString = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(imageData));

                          imageDataString2 = imageDataString.replace("_", "/");
                          imageDataString2 = imageDataString2.replace("-", "+");

                          System.out.println(imageDataString2);
                          base64 = imageDataString2;
                          System.out.println("Image Successfully Manipulated!");
                      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                          System.out.println("Image not found" + e);
                      } catch (IOException ioe) {
                          System.out.println("Exception while reading the Image " + ioe);
                      }                        
                       ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
                       Client client = Client.create(config);
                       WebResource service = client.resource(UriBuilder.fromUri("http://xxxxxx:8080/api").build());//change it to the latest URL 

                       Form f = new Form();                   
                       f.add("img",base64 );    

                       String s = service.post(String.class, f);

           } catch (Exception e) {

           }           
       }

   }).start();                         
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_2, container, false);
   }

    }
   ```

and here is the error:

```
03-28 03:50:24.569: W/dalvikvm(20989): Link of class 'Lcom/sun/jersey/core/osgi/OsgiRegistry;' failed
03-28 03:50:24.569: W/dalvikvm(20989): VFY: unable to resolve static method 5977: Lcom/sun/jersey/core/osgi/OsgiRegistry;.getInstance ()Lcom/sun/jersey/core/osgi/OsgiRegistry;
03-28 03:50:24.569: W/dalvikvm(20989): Link of class 'Lcom/sun/jersey/core/osgi/OsgiRegistry;' failed
03-28 03:50:24.569: W/dalvikvm(20989): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/sun/jersey/core/osgi/OsgiRegistry;)
03-28 03:50:27.379: W/dalvikvm(20989): Exception Ljava/lang/NullPointerException; thrown while initializing Lcom/sun/jersey/core/header/MediaTypes;
03-28 03:50:27.379: W/dalvikvm(20989): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
03-28 03:50:27.399: E/AndroidRuntime(20989): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
03-28 03:50:27.399: E/AndroidRuntime(20989): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
03-28 03:50:27.399: E/AndroidRuntime(20989):    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.getMessageBodyWriterMediaTypes(MessageBodyFactory.java:444)
03-28 03:50:27.399: E/AndroidRuntime(20989):    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter.getMediaType(RequestWriter.java:324)
03-28 03:50:27.399: E/AndroidRuntime(20989):    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter.writeRequestEntity(RequestWriter.java:282)
03-28 03:50:27.399: E/AndroidRuntime(20989):    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:213)
03-28 03:50:27.399: E/AndroidRuntime(20989):    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:149)
03-28 03:50:27.399: E/AndroidRuntime(20989):    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
03-28 03:50:27.399: E/AndroidRuntime(20989):    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:680)
03-28 03:50:27.399: E/AndroidRuntime(20989):    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.post(WebResource.java:251)
03-28 03:50:27.399: E/AndroidRuntime(20989):    at com.example.programming_fragments.Fragment_2$1.run(Fragment_2.java:91)
03-28 03:50:27.399: E/AndroidRuntime(20989):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
03-28 03:50:27.399: E/AndroidRuntime(20989): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 03:50:27.399: E/AndroidRuntime(20989):    at javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.java:119)
03-28 03:50:27.399: E/AndroidRuntime(20989):    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes.<clinit>(MediaTypes.java:65)
03-28 03:50:27.399: E/AndroidRuntime(20989):    ... 10 more
```

What should I do?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 03-28 03:50:27.399: E/AndroidRuntime(20989): at javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.java:119) ....

Answer (score 1):

im not sure this is right solution

according to [Jersey deps](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/chapter_deps.html#d4e1727) you need to have `jersey-json` module in your dependencies/classpath.

The library will be recognised if its name is libitv.so and is placed in libs\armeabi directory in your application directory, before the .apk is built.

Sometimes when the library is not copied completely(partial copy), due to some system issues the partial library too will not be recognized.

For more details refer [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html)

try this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-ndk/JyhjWs4VvwA) have some solution

**update:**

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Caused by: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:` Library jniavutil not found

You need to install libFLAC in addition to libsndfile. 
You can probably install libFLAC using whatever method you used 
to get libsndfile installed...

You have missed out the importent bits from the ddms log. Look for a
line that includes "caused by" and/or include more of the exception
log so we can have a look at it.

You've compiled with CodePro coverage enabled. Turn it off.

Actually this is the problem we are facing with ADT 17 you have to put your jar file into libs folder in order to overcome this exception

so right click on your project -->create a folder with name **libs**

and follow this step in

```
 right click (on libs folder) -->import-->File System-->browse to select your jar file and hit finish and run you project.
```

after that

```
 right click on the project --> Built Path-->java built path-->add jars select your jar file from your libs folder
```

if this also didn't work  rebuilding
everything (included data), and it will works.

Comment: I have jersey-bundle in my dependencies/classpath, isn't that enough

Comment: @MosabAldahayyat try my updated link it have some solution it will help you

Comment: Thank you @Sathish, i am putting the jar's in the libs and the java path but what i don't know is how i can install to my project and how to turn CodePro coverage off

Comment: Thank you all for helping me, i found that jersey-client is not supported in android OS and the alternative solution is to use Http post or get from Apache client.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342506/jersey-client-on-android-nullpointerexception